# My computer with Win10 freezes randomly

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, freeze

The short story is that my laptop started freezing randomly after I installed Win10 Pro (x64) on it.

Before I proceed any futher, please let me state that I have done my research and that I am aware that there can be multiple causes of random computer freezing. I have checked and verified all the possible causes that I came across but here is one possible issue that I can't eliminate as a potential root cause.

I came across an article describing random computer freezing after an upgrade to Win10 ([link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/80095788-85f1-4640-abdf-82f43cc5cc35/event-id-10016-the-applicationspecific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation?referrer=http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/80095788-85f1-4640-abdf-82f43cc5cc35/event-id-10016-the-applicationspecific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation?referrer=http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/80095788-85f1-4640-abdf-82f43cc5cc35/event-id-10016-the-applicationspecific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation?forum=win10itprohardware)).

I checked my Event Viewer and I came across this error:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
>   Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
>
> {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
>
> and APPID   {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
>
> to the user DESKTOP-OGJD845\g6-pavilion SID
>   (S-1-5-21-2661202775-3726479062-2032710083-1001) from address
>   LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
>   Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be
>   modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

[image]

I researched this issue further and came across a different post suggesting how to fix this error. ([link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/event-id-10016-the-application-specific-permission/9ff8796f-c352-4da2-9322-5fdf8a11c81e)).

I followed the instructions and managed to grand full control to "Administrators" via the registry editor.

[image]

[image]

I granted full rights to my "mysterious ID" as well - more details below.

[image]

[image]

I also looked up and changed the permissions under Component Services as per the instructions mentioned above.

[image]
[image]

I thought and hoped that it would eliminate the errors. However the issue seems to persist. I can still see the same error in the Even Viewer that I hoped to resolve.

I should perhaps mention that I can also see this "mysterious ID" as mentioned in this post - [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e7d85e3-d0e1-4e79-8141-0bbf8faf3644/windows-10-anniversary-update-the-case-of-the-mysterious-account-sid-causing-the-flood-of-dcom?forum=win10itprosetu).

So my question is: "How do I get rid of the DCOM errors?". I am not sure if those are the contributing factors to my random computer freezing but since others experience similar behaviour, I would like to get rid of those errors to eliminate them as the potential root cause of my laptop freezing.

Any tips would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Sounds to me that you may be chasing the wrong gremlin for the freeze problem actually..... as per Microsoft [*"**Workaround** 
You may change the permissions on DCOM components to prevent this error from being logged. However, this workaround may have side effects. It's better to just ignore these errors because they don't adversely affect functionality."*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022522/dcom-event-id-10016-is-logged-in-windows-10-and-windows-server-2016).   I think you go back to the drawing board and figure out what's really causing the freezing issue.

Comment: @Pimp Juice IT - Thank you! I came across this article before but decided to give the workaround a shot anyway. :)  I guess the workaround didn't work for me which the core of my question. I understand that the DCOM issue may not be the root cause of the freezing but I tried to get rid of the errors anyway to eliminate any potential sources of related or unrelated problems.

Comment: If you want to try something else, check out this post: http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-3128597/fix-windows-error-10016.html be sure to backup the registry container before you remove the keys but if this helps, tag me back and let me know and I'll be happy to add the content quoted and sourced from the post. It may be simply enough to test and eliminate this as a solution potentially so I wanted to run by you just in case.

Comment: Lastly, and I'll stop bugging you about this but I found this post https://shauncassells.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/windows-10-event-10016-fix-the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid-d63b10c5-bb46-4990-a94f-e40b9d520160-and-a/ and I just want you to look it over to ensure these are indeed the steps you followed per those specific CLSID `{~}` as this post gives the detailed instructions and what to select, etc. just to ensure you didn't have any oversight, it may be worth a quick read and verification to you.